# Error XLS0525 Method not found in type - when binding a generic delegate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, delegates

I am binding a property of a custom control to a `Func<object, bool>`. This works correctly at runtime but the designer complains...

Details - I have the following property in my viewmodel:

```
class Smth
{
    public Func<object, bool> TestToPerform
    {
        get
        {
            return TestToPerformFunc;
        }
    }

    protected abstract bool TestToPerformFunc(object item);
}
```

And then in XAML:

```
<local:ControlA
        TestToPerform="{Binding Foo.Bar.TestToPerform}" />
```

In the designer the text "`TestToPerform`" gets a blue underline and it shows the following error:

```
Error   XLS0525 Method 'TestToPerform' not found in type 'Smth'
```

The error of course is incorrect.

I tried to work around it with:

```
using FuncObjectBool = Func<object, bool>;
...

    public FuncObjectBool TestToPerform
    {
        get
        {
            return TestToPerformFunc;
        }
    }
```

But it had no beneficial effect.

I'm using VS2019 16.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a designer bug. And apparently will occur even without using generics.  It has been reported here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/997181/xls0525-error-when-attempting-to-bind-delegate-in.html

> XLS0525 error when attempting to bind delegate in WPF designer
> -
> Kevin Bost reported Apr 19 at 07:42 PM
>
> The problem reproduces with this sample project [here](https://github.com/Keboo/MaterialDesignInXaml.Examples/tree/master/DialogHost/DialogHost.AttachedPropertyClosing).
>
> The control, `DialogHost` exposes a delegate (`DialogClosingEventHandler`)
> dependency property. I am attempting to bind a public property in my
> view model to this property. The app compiles and runs successfully,
> with the delegate in my view model getting invoked. However in the
> designer I am getting a XLS0525 error. ...

A follow up comment states:

> Jun 03 at 06:43 AM A fix for this issue is now available in preview
> release.

With current status:

> **Fixed - Pending Release fixed in: visual studio 2019 version 16.7 preview 2**